# bootstrap vue b-table hangs or freezes some times that makes browser gets hang or stuck while searching or filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Btable freezes some times while filtring.

[image]

You can see the time difference where it freezes , this makes whole browser get hang or stuck

My Code

```
<b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Search files..." @keyup.native.esc="filter = ''"/>
<span v-if="filter" class="icon-clear" @click="filter = ''"></span>

<b-table show-empty striped outlined responsive hover no-sort-reset
             ref="table"
             empty-text="No files found"
             :items="items"
             :fields="fields"
             :filter="filter"
             :sort-by.sync="sort.field"
             :sort-desc.sync="sort.descending"
             :sort-direction="sort.direction"
             :current-page.sync="pagination.page"
             :per-page="pagination.size"
             @sort-changed="pagination.page=0"
             @filtered="onFiltered">
```

Why it is hapenning and how should i resolve this hanging issue

Comment: How many items are you showing per page?

Comment: it is not much it is 10 items per page

Comment: That's not a lot. That shouldn't be causing that many issues. How many fields, and total rows do you have?  Also, which version of `Bootstrap-Vue` are you using?

Comment: You might also want to add a debounce to your input via the `debounce` prop. Right now the table is trying to rerender on each keystroke.

Comment: total item is just 50 that is not much can you please help me to understand why table is trying to rerender on each keystroke?

Comment: It re-renders because the `filter` prop on the table changes. You write the character `A`, so the table sees that and starts filtering immediately for rows container the letter `A`. You then type the letter `B`, so now the `filter` changed again to `AB` and it starts all over again.

Comment: However, with just 50 rows, and 10 per page. There shouldn't be any issues even without a debounce. I think there's more going on that just the table. Are you on the latest version?

Comment: currently i am using 2.6.1

Comment: I believe there's been table optimizations after that. Try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213263/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-hiws).